# How to find the Lithium Contents of a Metal Battery, by knwing only the VOLTS

Tags: batteries, lithium, metal

How do we find the Lithium Contents of a Metal Battery, when the Batteries show only the VOLTS.

As per the IATA DGR, Metal Batteries can be accepted only when the Lithium contents are known ;  but the Batteries do not show the Lithium Contents, it shows only the Volts.

Comment: As batteries are manufactured goods ask the manufacturer

Comment: Metal Battery?  I'm not aware of any battery chemistry that does not involve one or more metals.

Answer (score 1):

If you need an accurate number, you will have to ask the maufacturer.

If you want a rough number... approximately 0.08g per watt-hour. This is addressed in more detail, with references, in this question: [How much lithium in lithium polymer batteries?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34501/how-much-lithium-in-lithium-polymer-batteries)

Answer (score 1):

> How do we find the Lithium Contents of a Metal Battery, when the Batteries show only the VOLTS.

You can't. That isn't even enough to make an estimate -- the lithium contents will roughly correspond to the energy capacity (e.g, watt-hours) of a battery, not to its terminal voltage.